# How can I put a <div> over an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a  directly on top of an image.

I have tried by giving both the image and the  z-index values (because normally the element with higher z index appears on the top, right?)

Comment: You'll need to post your code if you want us to help.

Comment: You have to use CSS with `position:absolute` on the div

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use CSS for this. Basically, HTML and CSS co-exist (check the dev tools, even if you haven't given any CSS, it will be having some CSS properties).

What you might need is something like this:

```css
figure,
figcaption {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

figure img {
  display: block;
}

figure figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3rcJO2J.jpg" alt="Image" width="200" />
  <figcaption>Hello!</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Note:** Use of `z-index` will work and be effective only if the element is given a `position` of `absolute` or `relative`. ps: `z-index` is CSS.

Comment: Thanks that made sense. But it seems I can't achieve it. Here's my code: http://i.imgur.com/0fxESte.png

Answer (score 2):

Here is an inline version of the same answer that I was working on.

```html
<div class="parent" style="position: relative;">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/500?image=13">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 170px;color: red;font-size: 100px;">My Div</div>
</div>
```